# Distance between point and subset in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq X$ a non-empty subset. For $x\in X$, define $P_A(x)=\{a\in A : d(a,x)=d(x,A)\}$, where $d(x,A):=\inf_{a\in A}d(a,x)$.

Suppose that $A$ has the following property: for every sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ such that $\lim d(a_n,x)=d(x,A)$, we have that $(a_n)$ has a subsequence that converges to an $a^*\in A$. Show that $P_A(x)$ is not empty.

My problem is that I don't know how to use this special property of $A$ because I can't really find a sequence to apply it.

Comment: Note the definition of $d(x,A)$ gives you a sequence $a_n$ such that ...

Comment: Hint: $d(x,A)+\frac1n$ cannot be a lower bound of $\{d(a,x):a \in A\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$d= \inf\{d(a,x) :a\in A\}=d(x, A ) $$
then by definition of infimum there esists a sequence $a_n\in A $ such that $$d(a_n , x )\to d $$ but fro the assumption there exists a subsequence $a_{n_k } \to a^*\in A $ since the meric $d $ is continous therefore $$d(x,a^* )=\lim_{k\to \infty} d(a_{n_k} ,x) =d=d(x, A)$$ hence $a^*\in P_A (x).$